# Webpack build failing on arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My Webpack build keeps failing on my React code which is like this

```
    ......
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.initmethod();
    }

    initmethod = () => {             // fails on this line near the first "="
    ......
```

These are my files

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'none',
    bail: true,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'commonjs react'
    }
};
```

I've tried all combinations of plugins and presets but still, the build is failing. This is my error:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: V:\GitHub\my-project\src\index.js Unexpected token (12:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:14)
```

Comment: Did you try this plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: Why did you not use [npx create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) besides babel obviously being mis configured I bet the linter isn't set up correctly either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just tried adding this. Still the same issue.

Comment: @HMR this is not a create-react-app application. I have a component which I need to push to npm. So I use webpack, along with babel to transpile and publish it to npm.